# Whats the best way to implement an event system in Game Maker?

Tags: events, game-maker

I'm currently working on a game that's going to be event heavy. So i'm looking for a scaleable way to handle these events. The event would be triggered either by a button click or an in game timer and would take the player to a screen that would print the text necessary for the event i.e "You've walked into an ambush!". It would then give the player options as to handle the situation in the form of button objects.

So seeing as my game will have possibly hundreds of these types of events i need a way to make the event screen dynamic if possible. But currently i cant find a way to implement this in gamemaker.

So is it possible or do i have to make individual rooms for each event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to make individual rooms for each event.

Make an object without any sprite that you'll use for `control` and place it in every room used in the game. You can test when an event occurs within the `step` condition of the `control` object, and you can print text and everything else in the `draw` condition.

A quick Google search yielded this tutorial: http://www.foobt.net/spring2015/csci11_8483/files/gamemaker-controller.html